# The Office.context.mailbox.item.conversationId in Outlook add-in returns undefined

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I tried to use conversationId in the Outlook add-in, but I am getting undefined. In the documentation it was given that I would not get the id for a new message but I tried to retrieve the id from an existing thread but was returning undefined. Any idea why the Id is undefined

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var conversationId = Office.context.mailbox.item.conversationId;
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**
I am on a Windows computer and using Chrome version Version 70.0.3538.110. The output of mailbox item :

```
{"_data$p$0":{"_data$p$0":{"extensionId":"xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx","marketplaceContentMarket":null,"permissionLevel":3,"marketplaceAssetId":null,"entryPointUrl":"https://localhost:3000/index.html","consentMetadata":null,"endNodeUrl":null,"hostVersion":"2018112401.04","owaView":"mouse","timeZoneOffsets":[{"start":-8640000000000000,"localStart":-8640000000000000,"end":8640000000000000,"localEnd":8640000000000000,"offset":330}],"userDisplayName":"Anto Joy","userEmailAddress":"outlook_xxxxxxxxxxxxx@outlook.com","userTimeZone":"India Standard Time","userProfileType":"enterprise","ewsUrl":"https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx","restUrl":"https://outlook.office365.com/api","itemType":4,"isRead":false},"_permissionLevel$p$0":2}}
```

Comment: Which client are you using? Are you using the rich desktop Outlook client on Windows, or on a Mac, or the web client in a browser?

Comment: the web client in a browser

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue on Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome on my Windows computer. Are you on a Windows computer or Mac? Which browser? My guess is that your Office.context.mailbox.item object is not null or undefined. If so, can you share the output of `JSON.stringify(Office.context.mailbox.item)`?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I have updated the question

Comment: Thanks. It appears you are in the new web view. I was able to reproduce this issue.